# How to get pagination working with "Pending" Posts

Tags: posts, categories, pagination, archives

I'm working on a site that allows users to browse through pending posts/content on the front-end.

However, I can't seem to get pagination working with those posts.  I've got a custom query that brings up the first page of pending posts on a category page, archive, etc.

But the Page 2, 3, etc.  doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Here's the example code I'm working with:

```
$args = array(
    'cat'      => $cat_ID,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'showposts' => 50,
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'post_status' => 'pending',

);

query_posts($args);

if( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

//Post code inserted here

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Post the code...?

Comment: I posted the code.  This works fine if the posted is published, but for pending posts, I can't seem to find a way to get it working.

Comment: Where is this code? More specifically is there a page that users navigate to to view the pending posts?

Comment: This actually is a modified category page. It works fine when loading that page, but /category/page/2/ does not load. I get a 404 error page. Basically its not finding the "pending posts" in this case. If I change the posts to "published" everything works fine (that is, the published posts show up on paginated pages.  Pending posts still do not show).  I think that Wordpress is just setup to only deal with published posts on paginated pages. I'm trying to find a way around that.

Comment: Yup, the problem is `query_posts` - so the user navigates to a particular category term page - which you use to display the pending posts? I ask, because it means I know what query you want to change as it goes through `pre_get_posts`

Comment: That's correct.  So what should I change the query to for that?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/paginate-custom-post-types/
It is meant for custom post type, but I think it would work for you too.

---

Edit:

The important part about this link is the link was the use of the first lines before the loop:

```
$temp = $wp_query; 
$wp_query = null; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query(here goes the query);
```

But I think a better solution would be to use pre_get_posts hook, I think it will solve your pagination problem, this is also the best practice.

You can use this code for your pagination:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'), 
'format' => '',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
'prev_text' => '',
'next_text' => ''
));
```

If you used the method with the WP_Query you should make sure you have this code at the end of your pagination code:

```
$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
```

Comment: You're linking to a "normal" paginated template code. Not even a good example of code: `wp_query->query('showposts=6&post_type=news'.'&paged='.$paged);
`. Looks funny...

Comment: Yea, this solution didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, best on your last comment 
"This actually is a modified category page. It works fine when loading that page, but /category/page/2/ does not load. I get a 404 error page. Basically its not finding the "pending posts" in this case..." You seems to have another problem, I thought you problem was to get the navigation working, not the pagiantion itself